# A and B have the same row space if and only if they are row equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent then they have the row space because elementary row operations do not change the row space.

I don't see how to prove that if $A$ and $B$ have the same row space then they are row equivalent. I've just noticed that if $A$ and $B$ have the same row space, then there exists matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $A = CB$ and $B = DA$. From there, I should prove that $C, D$ are invertible, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help from here?

Answer (score 1):

We say that two matrices $A, B$ are row equivalent if it is possible to transform $A$ into $B$ by one of the following elementary row operation:

- **Swap:** Swap two rows of a matrix.
- **Scale:** Multiply a row of a matrix by a nonzero constant.
- **Pivot:** Add a multiple of one row of a matrix to another row.

The matrices $C$ and $D$ you talked about are just a finite composition of these 3 operations. Try to show that these operations are invertible, then use the fact that a finite composition of invertible operations is invertible.

Comment: The problem is that I can't see why $C$ and $D$ are a finite composition of those $3$ operations. I've constructed $C$ so that in its $i$th row you have the coefficients that you have to use to write the $i$th row of $A$ as linear combination of the rows of $B$.

Comment: Well.. that's the definition of the matrix $C$ and $D$.

Comment: I only know that the row space of $A$ is equal to the row space of $B$, therefore I can write $A = CB$ and $B = DA$ because every row of $A$ can be written as a linear combination of the rows of $B$ and viceversa. How do you deduce that $C$ and $D$ are invertible?

Comment: Every linear combination is a finite composition of the three elementary operations I described above.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to point out that if $A$ and $B$ have the same row space, then there exist $m \times m$ matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $A = CB$ and $B = DA$. However, it is false that $C$ and $D$ are invertible. For a counterexample, take $A = B = C = D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

The following is my proof sketch. First show that if $A$ and $B$ are row-reduced echelon matrices with the same row space then they are row-equivalent. To get you started: note that $A = CDA$. Consider the properties of $CD$ (it's not necessarily invertible; however, it is invertible if $A$ does not have any non-zero rows). Once you've shown this, simply note that $A$ and $B$ can both be reduced to row-reduced echelon matrices without changing their row spaces.